# When cassandra-driver was executing the query, cassandra-driver returned error OperationTimedOut

Tags: python, cassandra, cql3

I use python script, that passes to cassandra batch query, like this:

```
query = 'BEGIN BATCH ' + 'insert into ... ; insert into ... ; insert into ...; ' + ' APPLY BATCH;'
session.execute(query)
```

It is work some time, but in about 2 minutes after start scripts fails and print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "/home/fervid/Desktop/cassandra/scripts/parse_and_save_to_cassandra.cgi", line 127, in <module><br>
    session.execute(query)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1103, in execute<br>
    result = future.result(timeout)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2475, in result<br>
    raise OperationTimedOut(errors=self._errors, last_host=self._current_host)<br>
cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1<br>
<br>
<br>
```

I changed timeout from `cassandra.yaml` to:
    
    read_request_timeout_in_ms: **15000**
    range_request_timeout_in_ms: **20000**
    write_request_timeout_in_ms: **20000**
    cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: **10000**
    request_timeout_in_ms: **25000**
    
    
**Then I restarted cassandra, but it didn't help.** The error happens again and again!

Lines in log near the time when script failed:

> INFO [BatchlogTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:10,490 ColumnFamilyStore.java
>   (line 794) Enqueuing flush of
>   Memtable-batchlog@28149592(13557969/13557969 serialized/live bytes, 4
>   ops)
>   INFO [FlushWriter:10] 2014-06-11 14:18:10,490 Memtable.java
>   (line 363) Writing Memtable-batchlog@28149592(13557969/13557969
>   serialized/live bytes, 4 ops)
>   INFO [FlushWriter:10] 2014-06-11
>   14:18:10,566 Memtable.java (line 410) Completed flushing; nothing
>   needed to be retained.  Commitlog position was
>   ReplayPosition(segmentId=1402469922169, position=27138996)
>   INFO
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:13,758 GCInspector.java (line 116)
>   GC for ParNew: 640 ms for 3 collections, 775214160 used; max is
>   1052770304
>   INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:16,155
>   GCInspector.java (line 116) GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 1838 ms for 2
>   collections, 810976000 used; max is 1052770304
>   INFO
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,959 GCInspector.java (line 116)
>   GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 1612 ms for 1 collections, 858404088 used;
>   max is 1052770304
>   INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,959
>   StatusLogger.java (line 55) Pool Name                    Active
>   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
>   INFO
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,959 StatusLogger.java (line 70)
>   ReadStage                         0         0            627         0
>   0
>   INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,960
>   StatusLogger.java (line 70) RequestResponseStage              0
>   0              0         0                 0
>   INFO
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,960 StatusLogger.java (line 70)
>   ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0
>   0
>   INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,960
>   StatusLogger.java (line 70) MutationStage                     0
>   0         184386         0                 0
>   INFO
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-06-11 14:18:17,960 StatusLogger.java (line 70)
>   ReplicateOnWriteStage             0         0              0         0
>   0

Comment: check cassandra logs.. so that you will come to know the the error behind it..

Comment: I don't see anything ERROR messages in log... Only INFO messages.

Comment: ok..
in cassandra.yaml file things has to be like
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 15000 not like
read_request_timeout_in_ms: **15000**<br>

and increase 

cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 60000 (some more)

Comment: There are no '**' in config, it appeared after i had tried to make numbers bold:)

Comment: I have increased cas_contention_timeout_in_ms to 60000 just now. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 17):

1. This is a client side timeout (see the link in @Syrial's reply: http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra.html#cassandra.OperationTimedOut)
2. You can change the `Session` [default timeout](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.default_timeout):

   ```
   session = cluster.connect()
   session.default_timeout = 30  # this is in *seconds*
   ```
3. You can change [the timeout for a particular query](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute):

   ```
   session.execute(statement, 30, ...)
   ```
4. You could speed up the execution quite a bit by using prepared statements inside the `BATCH`. See the [Batching statements sections in this post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-2-0-released)
5. If you are after even better results, please read these [performance notes](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/performance.html)

Comment: I solve this problem by dividing whole query into smaller queries.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, this error is saying that the operation took longer than specified on the client-side.  The error is generated by the driver, not Cassandra.  I'm still searching for a way to handle this error myself.

http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra.html#cassandra.OperationTimedOut

Comment: Yes, this error generated by cassandra. But cassandra settings may cause such driver behaviour and so i attempted to change it.